# VirtueMart - limit delivery to all countries but one?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I need to set shipping fee for one country and for shipping to all other countries all across the globe the shipping is higher. Standard situation. My idea: create two shipping methods. The first only for that one country and the second for all other countries. How to limit the second method to be for all countries but one? Or is there another solution for this situation?

Comment: `switch($country){ case 'USA': /*something*/ break; default: /*something else*/ break; }` perhaps?

Comment: I'm not searching for a solution that requires modifying the code. You can select countries for which the shipping method to be viable. I need to know how I can exclude the selected countries.

Comment: You didn't tell which Virtuemart version you are using. In the 1.x you would go to "Shipping -> Shipping rates" tab in shop Admin area and select all available countries, but one you don't want in multiple-select list

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know that VirtueMart supports the use of only ONE shipping method at a time, so there is no way to combine the use of two separate methods within a single order.

However, one of the non-commercial shipping methods available for VirtueMart is called Flex2.  It works similarly to the standard Flex shipping module, except it allows you to define TWO "zones".  The first zone is known as "Domestic", while the second is called "International".

When configuring the Flex2 module, enter the name of your "one country" into the spot reserved for the Domestic Country.  By default, all other countries will be considered "International" and will use the second set of shipping parameters.

If your followup question (about limiting the second method to all countries except one) was designed to omit the country named in the first part, you don't have to worry about that, as this is implicitly how the Flex2 shipping module works.

Flex2 is only compatible with Virtuemart 1.x and Joomla 1.5.x.